# Get Claims from SWT Token

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, access-token, claims

I have successfully authenticated my Azure Media Services account in my ASP.Net Core app, server side. Azure returns a Simple Web Token (SWT) which also contains claims with the expiration timestamp of this token.

The token looks like this:

> http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=healthtrainee&urn%3aSubscriptionId=bc73f3ce-aafe-40ff-bd14-56bd5969b725&http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fwamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&Audience=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices&**ExpiresOn=1493595982**&Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fwamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&HMACSHA256=a1tBHoUzli1oEzzGwYGcqdE5EGJAv8xPXzz4XWB5EBo%3d

How can I get the claims out of this token in order to handle the token lifecycle (to refresh if necessary).
I am sure there is something out there which saves me from parsing this by my own.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the claims out of this token in order to handle the token lifecycle (to refresh if necessary).

Normally, if we use [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-connect-programmatically#getting-an-access-token) to get an access token, we could retrieve the `access_token` and `expires_in` (indicates the number of seconds for which the access token is valid) values in the response body, and then we could cache the values to an external storage and monitor the `expires_in` value and ensure that the access token has not expired.

Besides, if we use Media Services SDK, we could also [retrieve and cache the AccessToken string and the TokenExpiration values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-connect-programmatically#reusing-access-control-service-tokens), and then monitor&ensure TokenExpiration is not expired.

```
var accessToken = _context.Credentials.AccessToken;
var tokenExpiration = _context.Credentials.TokenExpiration;
```

Comment: Thanks. This would be plan b for me, i.e. using the expires_in value to calculate the expiration timestamp. I hoped to be able to use the expiration timestamp in the token to avoid storing kind of "redundant" information. The second suggestion utilizing the Media Services SDK is not an option for me as I am using .Net Core and the SDK is not supporting Core afaik.

Comment: ``I hoped to be able to use the expiration timestamp in the token to avoid storing kind of "redundant" information.`` If you really want to extract **ExpiresOn** part from SWT, you could try to write a regular expression to match piece across all the token string.